# Cannot install Xubuntu 16.04.3 from USB drive

Tags: xubuntu

I have created USB from 16.04.3 iso image and install starts.

It gets stuck on

```
"A start job is running for Ubuntu Live CD installer (10 min 45 s /no limit). "
```

and it never stops. I'm trying to install to USB thumb drive also.

Comment: Have you figured out what may causes this issue?